# How to get Good CRC16 from string in java?

Tags: java, android, crc16

I am trying to get CRC16 from string in android application using following code

```
static int crc16(final byte[] buffer) {
int crc = 0xFFFF;

for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length ; j++) {
    crc = ((crc  >>> 8) | (crc  << 8) )& 0xffff;
    crc ^= (buffer[j] & 0xff);//byte to int, trunc sign
    crc ^= ((crc & 0xff) >> 4);
    crc ^= (crc << 12) & 0xffff;
    crc ^= ((crc & 0xFF) << 5) & 0xffff;
}
crc &= 0xffff;
return crc;

}
```

and I have some data to verify the result as below table

[image: expected result]

when I am passing `A` to that function I am getting `B915` which is bad CRC and same for all. why I am not able to get Good CRC as mentioned in table. please correct me where I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `Bad_CRC` because you are calculating `Bad_CRC` by using `0xFFFF`. If you want to calculate `Good_CRC` then replace it with `0x1D0F`.

[image]

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String input = "A";
    Integer crcRes = crc16(input.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Calculated CRC-CCITT: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(crcRes));
}

private static int crc16(final byte[] buffer) {
    /* Note the change here */
    int crc = 0x1D0F;
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length ; j++) {
        crc = ((crc  >>> 8) | (crc  << 8) )& 0xffff;
        crc ^= (buffer[j] & 0xff);//byte to int, trunc sign
        crc ^= ((crc & 0xff) >> 4);
        crc ^= (crc << 12) & 0xffff;
        crc ^= ((crc & 0xFF) << 5) & 0xffff;
    }
    crc &= 0xffff;
    return crc;
}
```

Output:

```
Calculated CRC-CCITT: 0x9479
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its solved.

Comment: No. This is just a bandaid. The CCIT CRC-16 is defined as having an initial value of 0xffff. The only other initial value in common use is zero. Find the bug in your code and fix it. There are plenty of working examples available, including a table-driven algorithm that is eight times as fast,

Comment: @EJP `0xFFFF` is used to calculate `Bad_CRC`. `0x1D0F` should be used to calculate `Good_CRC`. Kermit is one other variation of `CRC-CCITT`. I do not see any bug in this code. Correct me if I'm wrong.